# Is testing based on API a black-box test or a grey-box test?

Tags: testing, refactoring, theory, agile

Is testing based on an API (like a Javadoc)  a black box or grey box test?

**What I think**

I think it is grey box, testing.

Why

1. Black box test is when we DONT have  knowledge of the system and its inner workings. However since we are given the API, we know the return types, the parameters passed, etc  we have  general albeit basic understanding of what each  method should do and the inner workings of the system.

Also  if you recall the meaning of grey box testing :  A test is designed based on the knowledge of algorithm, architectures, internal states, or other high -level descriptions of the program behavior.

Since we have the API, we can design some test cases, which will be of relatively high/medium coverage.

Answer (score 0):

API Testing is not inherently black, grey, or white-box testing. As you say, it's all about the knowledge. If I'm working with the API in the same way anyone in the public would, we could call that black box testing because I'm at the same knowledge level. On the other hand, if I'm an internal tester and I can open up the source code and ask the developers questions, it's white-box. And honestly, grey is just in-between.

All that said, there is no standard strict definition for these terms and therefor no real demarcation line for when testing switches from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your testing is working only with the inputs and the outputs of the API it is black box testing.

When you start to test APIs looking also at source code coverage then it is gray or even more.